# creating a element in javascript with onclick function which passes $_session var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, dom

What I want in html code:

```
<a onclick="DeleteImage('javascript:this.id', <?=$_SESSION['UserID']?>)"></a>
```

which passes the var userid from `$_session` to the javascript function:

```
function DeleteImage(aid,userid){}
```

This worked when i didnt had to pass the `$_session` variable and only had this function

```
function DeleteImage(aid){}
```

Then i could create the a element in javascript like this:

```
cross = document.createElement('a');
cross.onclick = function() { DeleteImage(this.id) };
```

How can I create the a element so it generates the html code i want?
I want something like:

```
cross.onclick = function() { DeleteImage(this.id, "<?=$_SESSION['UserID']?>") };
```

which obviously does not work. Any help appreaciated :)

Comment: It may work if the script is generated by PHP (for example, embedded in the page). I guess it's not the case?

Comment: I have the script which will create this element in a seperate file which cannot reach $_session

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the way you retrieve an information like `$_SESSION['UserID']`. An interesting option would be creating a `data` attribute, for example in the `<html>` tag itself:

```
<html data-user-id="<?=$_SESSION['UserID']?>">
```

Then all you have to do is to retrieve that value in the `DeleteImage` function itself:

```
function DeleteImage(aid) {
    var userId = document.documentElement.getAttribute("data-user-id");
    ...
}
```

And you're done, you can call `DeleteImage` with the old way. (Note: you can also use `document.documentElement.dataset.userId` in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. There are partial polyfills for IE, but I guess they're not worth the effort in your case.)

You can even save some extra cycles retrieving the value at the beginning of the script and storing it in a scoped variable:

```
var userId = document.documentElement("data-user-id");
function DeleteImage(aid) {
    ...
}
```

Slightly off topic, may I suggest to using some more modern way to attach event listeners? And maybe considering some kind of [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)?

Comment: Putting that kind of info into `meta` elements is just terrible, don’t do that. If you want a value to be available _to_ JavaScript, then you can simple have PHP write code that _creates_ a JS variable.

Comment: It works if I fetch the meta element within my function but for some reason it doesnt work if i fetch it from outside. It does not matter to me but I just wanted to point it out :) I am new to javascript programming, will definitely check out events. thanks

Comment: how can i do that? @CBroe

Comment: You do know how a JavaScript variable and its value assignment are written _statically_, don’t you …? So then where’s the problem in replacing the value assignment part with one generated by PHP?

Comment: worked just as good, but now i dont  have to have the meta tag. <script>var userId = <?=$_SESSION['UserID']?>;</script>

Comment: @CBroe can you explain why is it terrible? It's just a way as many others. Some may argue that mixing HTML and inline scripts is terrible, or creating a global variable.

Comment: Meta elements are supposed to transport information about the document itself, and not additional (and always changing) info that a certain script might need. And I did not necessarily say the variable should be global; and if you’re against inline scripts, then use f.e. a custom data attribute in an appropriate place instead.

Comment: And apart from that, in this special case here I don’t even see what good it should/could possibly do to transport the user id to the JS in the first place – I doubt that there is any need for this value _client-side_ in the deletion of an image (whatever exactly that entails); and if this JS triggers something _server-side_, then there is a) no need to pass that value through the client and back, since the server has it in the session anyways, and b) it might add an additional vulnerability if the user _changes_ it and the _passed_ value is relied on server-side afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe You raise some good points, in particular about the client that should deal with the user id. But while we have no additional informations about the kind of the page, using a meta tag isn't more harmful than other options. For the sake of semantics, I'm changing the code.